# accessNotConfigured error (403) from Youtube API via google-api-php-client

Tags: youtube-data-api, google-api-php-client

I've followed all the steps and can use the api console to create event and edit event, but I'm unable to programmatically get same to work from my code, using the API PHP library from Google.

The error I get is: `"domain": "usageLimits", "reason": "accessNotConfigured", "message": "Access Not Configured. YouTube Data API has not been used in project......."`

Anyone else had any similar experiences with the API and any success getting past this?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and resolved it by starting from scratch and creating a new project, then creating an API key on the new project. Everything worked fine then!